# Source for calling the head table, Mizrah, like in "Rabbis sit at the Mizrah"

Tags: minhag

In Israel, when an important Orthodox event is held (convention, family celebration, etc), a head table is set at the front to accommodate the most honorable Rabbis. This is called "the Mizrah".

[image]

What is the source of calling the head table "Mizrah"?

Comment: I've never heard of this naming convention before.

Comment: I would assume it derives from the ‘mizrach vant’ the eastern (front) wall of an Ashkenazi synagogue, along which dignitaries would sit

Comment: Calling it Mizrach is connected to the layout of the Beit HaMikdash. Menorah and Shulchan for the Lechem HaPanim to the south and north and the Shechinah to the west. That's also the preferred way to set up the Shabbat table at home.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mizrah